# Why does an Agentset button behave different than an observer button asking the agentset?

Tags: netlogo

I see a behavior difference between an agentset button (patch, turtle, link) which runs a certain section of code and an observer button which `ask`s `patches` (or `turtles`, or `links`) to run the same section of code. Is this a bug in NetLogo? Is this a bug in my code?

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the behavior difference isn't actually a bug, but a rather obscure corner of NetLogo. The [`ask-concurrent`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask-concurrent) primitive lies at the core of this behavior. An agentset button uses the same mechanism as `ask-concurrent` behind the scenes. Replacing any agentset button with an observer button which uses `ask-concurrent` to run the same code on the same agentset shouldn't change the behavior of the button.

Typically the differences between `ask` and `ask-concurrent` don't amount to much. Turtles may move *slightly* differently, but it will work basically the same. In some cases though, the differences can be really dramatic. The NetLogo Models Library provides a model called "Ask-Concurrent Example" which explores the differences between `ask` and `ask-concurrent`.

There is also documentation on this in the NetLogo Programming Guide, in the "Turtle, patch, and link forever buttons" section of http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#buttons; much of the section on  ask-concurrent at http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask-concurrent also applies.

**Note**: Use of `ask-concurrent` isn't recommended. I'm using it here to clarify the behavior, but it should **not** be used in general.

**Note 2**: In general, the safest and most predictable approach is not to use turtle, patch, and link buttons at all. Instead, use observer buttons only, and use `ask turtles`, `ask patches`, or `ask links` in the button code, as appropriate.